# Python "unresolved import" in PyDev but found at command line

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pydev

I installed win32api and can import and make calls to it from the command line but the same import isn't found when written in Eclipse (using PyDev). The cwd and path match from cmd line to PyDev (sys.path and os.getwd()). What could cause the discrepancy?

Comment: Have you refreshed the PyDev Interpreter?  That's usually enough to find / reindex installed modules so that the import statements recognize them properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely need to go into the Interpreter Settings and refresh the Include Paths.  Choose Window > Preferences.  Expand PyDev, click on Interpreter - Python. Choose your Interpreter, then hit the Apply button.  If you haven't made any other changes it'll rescan the site-packages directory looking for new modules.  If it doesn't automatically find these two, add them yourself:

```
c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32
c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
```

With those two directories on in its Path it should see the win32api module correctly.

Comment: You may end up changing `Python26` to the directory for your installed version if you're using something other than 2.6, but otherwise, this should work for you.  Afterwards, Eclipse should see the module and provide code completion / etc as usual.

Comment: What pydev tutorial recommends afair is to delete the interpreter and then reload it afresh. not sure it is the same

Comment: @joaquin - Refreshing accomplishes the same thing, and usually saves you from having to re-assign an interpreter to your projects.  Otherwise though, I think they're pretty analogous.

Comment: Interpreters in PyDev are identified only by their names. That's why after deleting given interpreter and then creating a new one with the same name you don't have to reassign it to the projects.

Comment: Thanks much! @joaquin is also right. I tried a refresh and didn't find the module. Removing/adding the interpreter did the trick. And if you give it the same name as before that's all there is too it. Thanks Piotr Dobrogost for that.